# Start scheme with 'scheme' instead of 'mit-scheme-x86-64'

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I started using Ubuntu to learn how to use terminal and program and stuff. So I found a way to get scheme on my machine because I'm reading Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs but I have to type 'mit-scheme-x86-64' instead of 'scheme' which is what I would prefer to type.

Is there a way to map 'scheme' to that longer phrase? If so, what is that even called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.  The simplest is to create an alias.  Run this at the bash command line:

```
alias scheme='mit-scheme-x86-64'
```

If you like that alias, put it in your `~/.bashrc` file and it will be available to you in every shell that you open.

Answer (score 0):

At the link of [IstallingMITScheme](https://wiki.umn.edu/CSCI1901/InstallingMITScheme) I found this fix.

> As the package works now it doesn't properly start with typing scheme. To fix this run "sudo ln -s -T /usr/local/bin/mit-scheme-x86-64 /usr/local/bin/mit-scheme". You should be able to use scheme just like at school.

I am also beginning to work through MIT-OCW's courses 6.001 to 6.006 and have tried to install scheme on Ubuntu 14.04. Using the method that I found at the above link is what seemed to work for my 64-bit system. (Thought I did have to run `sudo apt-get -f install` to install the missing dependency files)